# Hibernate HQL doesn`t recognize "OUTER APPLY" as a keyword

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have written this query in spring boot, and I am getting this error while building the project. Any help?

```
@Query("SELECT Appointments.InsuranceBillingSequence"+
            "FROM PatientInfo P OUTER " +
            "APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 APT.InsuranceBillingSequence FROM [Appointments] APT" +
            "WHERE APT.LicenseKey=P.LicenseKey and APT.PatientFID = P.Patient_UID and" +
            "APT.Appointment_UID in ?3) Appointments" +
            "WHERE P.Id=?1 AND P.LicenseKey=?2")
    List<InsuranceDetailsDTO> findPatientInfoWithInsuranceDetails(String id, Integer licenseKey, 
                                                                  List<Integer> visits);
```

**Error:-** ast.ErrorCounter:org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError(ErrorCounter.java:60) - line 1:651: unexpected token: OUTER*

Comment: OUTER APPLY is specific to SQLServer (google tells me), if you want to use it you'll have to run a native query. Otherwise you'll have to stick to what JPQL supports.

Comment: Is `APPLY ` a supported JPQL keyword? Maybe you need `nativeQuery=true`

Comment: Making it a native query solves the problem. Thank you both!